# Joining 3 larges tables into 1 table with 1 to many relationship in Google BigQuery

Tags: join, google-bigquery, denormalization

I have only started working with BigQuery recently and would like to join 3 tables with 1:many relationship (10M (fact), 20M and 36M rows respectively) into one single table to use in Tableau.
Is there any advice or guidance on how to go about this without hitting performance issues or any other consideration?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: You should write a little more detail about what your tables look like, what type of output you are expecting, and what have you tried doing so far to get your desired results.

Comment: Thanks. To be precise then, l would like to join the main fact table A (10M records) to tables B and C (respectively 20M and 36M records). A is linked to B by 1: many and B linked to C by 1 : many relationship. My intention is to use the join to get one single table. Is using join the right approach to take here given the size of the data or is there any alternative?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the `JOINS` in your situation is the right way to go. From what it looks like (without knowing your tables structure), you should start from:

```sql
   select 
     ct.some_thing as c_field, 
     bt.some_thing as b_field, 
     a.some_thing as a_field 
   from C ct 
   left join B bt on ct.some_field = bt.some_field 
   left join A at on bt.some_field = at.some_field
```

Comment: Thank you @khan. I will definitely give it a go. Also, l wonder what's the best way to store the results of the JOINS in a new table? if any, can this process Automated inside BQ so the table can be refreshed periodically? Thanks

Comment: You can use [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) in BQ to save your joined results and connect your tableau to the partitioned table to query data for one partition at a time. You can automatically overwrite or append to a partition in your table.

Comment: Thanks again. I have read the documentation on the partioned tables. Although that the data contains date field (which can be used for the partition),   I wonder if that's applicable in my case because the goal is to show the entire data in the report. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That will actually save you on number of bytes scanned if tableau only queries a particular partition at a time.